# Where do X error messages go?

Tags: xorg, logs

If I start an X application from a terminal, the error messages go to the terminal. If I start them from a  GUI, where do the error messages go, or alternatively how are they dealt with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display managers such as *xdm* & *gdm* usually capture stderr from the processes they start and log it to a file such as `/var/log/xdm.log` or `/var/log/gdm/:0.log`.  That includes the output from the X server being started.

Once your session starts, it may redirect output from the session processes to a file such as `~/.xsession-errors` as tante pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Usually all generic X errors (and those of some applications) go to the file `~/.xsession-errors`.

Answer (score 0):

They go to whatever terminal the X server was started from. If you boot to command line and then start X, you can see them by hopping back to that VT (hit Ctrl-Alt-F1). If you boot directly to X, I'm not sure where the messages show up by default; it may vary by distro.

Comment: The question explicitly mentioned login from a GUI session manager.