# Where is the logging of an application launched from the GUI buffered before being sent to a log file?

Tags: logs, stdout

This is a fairly difficult question for me to word, but I'll try my best.

When I launch an application from the terminal, say, Banshee as an example (so `banshee` to launch from terminal), I can see all the logging of the application. But when I launch it from my GUI menu, I obviously don't see the same logging, as it doesn't launch it through a terminal emulator. Generally, the application redirects the logging to some log file. I have two questions about this:

1. Does the application send all its logging to `stdout` first, which is then tee'd to the log file?
2. Is there a way to access this `stdout` "buffer"? (I am not sure if buffer is the right word, but it seems correct to me right now).

If this question isn't clear, please post in comments and I will do my best to fix it.

EDIT

I run Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Apps log to journal nowadays (in linux that is). So `journalctl` is your friend.

Comment: What desktop environment or window manager are you using, on what distribution? The general principle is the same but the specifics vary.

Comment: @don_crissti What systems redirect the output of GUI programs to the systemd journal?

Comment: @Gilles I edited my question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa, and the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/where-do-x-error-messages-go) worked for me. I ran:

```
cat ~/.xsession-errors | head --lines=-10
```

to view the last 10 lines of a Java stacktrace generated by double clicking a runnable-jar.